# How do I brute force a sha256 hash in the specified block

Tags: python-3.x, brute-force

I am currently writing a function that attempts to brute force the sha256 hash, prints the number, and exits the loop when it finds a match. 
The code I worked on prints the hash and encodes it in utf-8:

```
#!/bin/python3
import hashlib
import sys
                 # First argument passed to the script 
inputhash=sys.argv[1]
def passthehash(hash):
        for pin in range(1000000):

                inputhash = hashlib.sha256(str(f'{pin:06}').encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

passthehash(inputhash)
```

After a bit of browsing, I implemented the code and ran the program, which gave me:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testing3.py", line 5, in <module>
    inputhash=sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am new to this type of error, so I do not understand why this particular list index is out of range.

Comment: you need to pass in an argument to the script when you run it in command line. How are you running the python script ? If you're using command line, post a screen shot or the command you typed.

Comment: the question is about list out of index, so you can remove the tags for hash, sha 256 etc..

Comment: No command line, except for chmod +x and ./ are used for execution.

Comment: post a sample input, also edit the name of your question, because the problem is not related to hashing

Answer (score 1):

```
inputhash=sys.argv[1]
```

is looking for a command line parameter to be passed into the script.

like this: $ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3

because you are not passing in any arguments, it will error when you try and access the argument with argv[1]

Please refer to this tutorial: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's like this. you have a list. a = [1, 2]
And this code:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    print(a[i])
```

It would print 1 and 2. But there's no a[2]. This is IndexError.